# Codeigniter query does not insert

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

The data is being sent from the front end like this:

```
var data = {
                'user_id':userid,
                'qid':array[qnum].qid,
                'user_ans':userAnswers[qnum].answer,
                'user_time':userTime,
                'exerciseid':exid,
                'point_scored':points
        };
$.post('<?php echo base_url()?>main/update_user_score',
            { myData : data },
            function(result){} );
```

And in my "main" controller, I have:

```
$post_data = $_POST['myData'];

$data = array(
            'user_id' => $post_data[user_id] ,
            'qid' => $post_data[qid],
            'user_ans' => $post_data[user_ans],
            'user_time' => $post_data[user_time],
            'exerciseid' => $post_data[exerciseid],
            'point_scored' => $post_data[point_scored]
        );

$this->load->model('Question_model','questions');
$this->questions->update_user_attempt($data);
```

In my Question_model / update_user_attempt:

```
error_log("data in model BEFORE INSERT:" . json_encode($data));
$this->db->insert('user_attempt', $data);
error_log("data in model AFTER INSERT: ");
```

The problem is, the data reaches (at least seems to me) the model quite fine. Here's the log entry:

```
[23-Apr-2012 16:04:47] data in model BEFORE INSERT:{"user_id":"5","qid":"3","user_ans":"d","user_time":"3","exerciseid":"cr1","point_scored":"35"}
```

**BUT** there is NO "after insert" log entry. The insert itself does not happen, and neither does the log entry after the insert.

I can read from the DB quite fine. So I checked in phpmyadmin the user privileges of the user in "config/database.php", and that user has *ALL* privileges, including INSERT.

So two questions:

1. What is the problem? What mistake am I making?
2. How do I even begin finding out what is going on with the insert statement? (I cannot find anything in the logs.)
3. I am looking at xampp/apache/logs/error.log and xampp/php/logs/php_error_log. Should I be looking at some other logs?

Answer (score 3):

Try putting $this->db->_error_message(); after db insert

like this ...

```
error_log("data in model BEFORE INSERT:" . json_encode($data));
$this->db->insert('user_attempt', $data);
echo $this->db->_error_message();
error_log("data in model AFTER INSERT: ");
```

Comment: Where does this get echoed out to? Since this is an ajax call, I cannot see the data on screen. Can I send it out to some log file?

Comment: Use firebug, or a similar plugin, to view the response of the ajax call.  It'll show you exactly what your script outputs.

Comment: It was a stupid mistake. Found that it was failing a foreign key error. Had not known how to check the Ajax responses. Now I know.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to use `$this->db->last_query()` after your insert statement to see what the insert statement looks like. copy and paste that insert statement into your sql client to see if the query is actually working on its own.

Comment: Prints an empty string. Does that mean the query is not getting formed??

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
```

Also before your insert,

```
var_dump($data); die();
```

to see exactly what you are passing.  Then check [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#insert) to see that you are properly forming the insert statment.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you missing this

```
$post_data['user_id']
```

Instead you are using without quotes

Comment: I had originally put the quotes, and had removed them because I was so frustrated, I would try anything. Later realized that the query was failing a foreign key constraint. Had not known how to check that earlier. Now I know!
Sorry for the trouble, and thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing I thought was: shouldn't you use json_decode in stead of json_encode?
2. Did you set `error_reporting(E_ALL);`?

Comment: After I added error_reporting(E_ALL) to the model, just before the insert, I still dont see any changes / new log entries.

I am looking at xampp/apache/logs/error.log and xampp/php/logs/php_error_log . Should I be looking somewhere else?